# 'react-router-dom' does not contain an export named 'useHistory'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-install

Im trying to import useHistory from react-router-dom but it keeps giving me the error 'react-router-dom' does not contain an export named 'useHistory'.

React-router-dom's version is 4.3.1 and i've tried updating (in case there was an updated version) but every time i do npm install react-router-dom it always just installs 4.3.1  It updated react-router from 4.3.1 to 5.2.0 just fine so i don't know why react-router-dom doesn't update (if there is an updated version).

If anyone knows another way to import useHistory or make a back button that goes to the previous URL from anywhere I'd love to know.

Comment: You need to import useHistory from react-router-dom.                                                          As, import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

Comment: @MayuriPapat - The OP should definitely have shown their code, but the only way they're going to get the error in the title is if that is the code they were using.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"useHistory" is replaced by "useNavigate", in "react-router-dom" v.6

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const navigateTo = useNavigate();
navigateTo('/your-page')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can update `react-router-dom` package by manually changing the version in `package.json` to `5.2.0`

or

install the specific version by using the below command

```
npm i react-router-dom@5.2.0
```

or the latest version like

```
npm i react-router-dom@latest
```

Comment: Glad to have helped